# Can you define a class static constant at namespace scope with auto?

Tags: c++

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), it's possible to define `const` `static` data members from within the `class` definition without defining it at namespace-scope. Doing so is valid so long as the constant is not ODR-used; this practice effectively does not provide a storage-backing in the translation-unit. For example:

```cpp
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t

class my_string
{
public:
    static const auto npos = static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);
};
```

I like to follow almost-always-auto guidelines where possible to achieve a consistent left-to-right readability while also keeping the typing generic. However, this is at odds with the few cases where you may actually *want* that symbol to be possibly ODR used. What I would *like* to do is:

```cpp
#include "my_string.hpp"

const auto my_string::npos; // error!
```

However, this [fails](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rhhx63) even under c++20 due to the type not being specified -- despite the fact that `decltype(my_string::npos)` is already known by this point. Ideally, I'd like the namespace-definition to not necessitate a change if ever the constant's type changes.

**My question is:** Is there any way to achieve a simple left-to-right syntax in such a scenario?

The only two ways I can think of to solve this are to either *not* specify the namespace-definition using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s `inline` variables, or to name the type by using `decltype(my_string::npos)` (which, though ugly, does work).

Comment: What's wrong with c++17 `inline`?

Comment: If I want to define a compiler-specific attribute on it (e.g. using custom sections), I would rather internalize this in the `*.cpp` file rather than to tag this into my `class` where everyone sees it. But I still want the definition to be in the header so that optimizations may occur where its not ODR used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> despite the fact that decltype(my_string::npos) is already known by this point

Well.. so just use it!

```
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
class my_string {
public:
    static const auto npos = static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);
};
const decltype(my_string::npos) my_string::npos; // all fine!
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more elegant answer than this (since I already mention this being a possible way to achieve this in the question), but... I'm guessing there isn't any other way. Oh well.